# Simple JSON request from URL

Tags: jquery, html, json

I've been scrolling through the message boards for a couple of days now but I can't seem to get this working... I'm new to JSON and am trying to just return one value from this object in the URL but can't seem to even get my demo working :(

Any advice of how to resolve this would be much appreciated, I imagine it's something really simple I'm missing but I can't for the life of me work out what it is... thanks!

```js
var text = $.getJSON('https://api.waqi.info/feed/london/?token=1f3f4bd260b5067cd3a4397ae81ac18a1e03f246', function(data) {
});


obj = JSON.parse(text);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
obj.data[0].aqi;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Output</h2>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Edit:

Here is the object:

```js
{  
   "status":"ok",
   "data":{  
      "aqi":111,
      "idx":5724,
      "attributions":[  
         {  
            "url":"http://uk-air.defra.gov.uk/",
            "name":"UK-AIR, air quality information resource - Defra, UK"
         },
         {  
            "url":"http://londonair.org.uk/",
            "name":"London Air Quality Network - Environmental Research Group, King's College London"
         }
      ],
      "city":{  
         "geo":[  
            51.5073509,
            -0.1277583
         ],
         "name":"London",
         "url":"http://aqicn.org/city/london/"
      },
      "dominentpol":"pm25",
      "iaqi":{  
         "co":{  
            "v":0.1
         },
         "h":{  
            "v":45
         },
         "no2":{  
            "v":70.5
         },
         "o3":{  
            "v":15
         },
         "p":{  
            "v":995
         },
         "pm10":{  
            "v":50
         },
         "pm25":{  
            "v":111
         },
         "so2":{  
            "v":5.7
         },
         "t":{  
            "v":19.23
         }
      },
      "time":{  
         "s":"2017-05-11 15:00:00",
         "tz":"+00:00",
         "v":1494514800
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in the javascript console?

Comment: I get this:
`"message": "Script error.",`
`"filename": "",`
`"lineno": 0,`
`"colno": 0 `

Comment: Can you show the obj, what it have ?

Comment: @SKJajoriya have updated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many issues at play here.

First, per [jQuery docs for `$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), that method doesn't return the fetched JSON. It returns the [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) that was produced to make the request. `$.getJSON` is an asynchronous function to which you can pass a callback function that will receive the fetched data after said fetch is complete. You can also use the returned `jqXHR` to run code after success by means of the promise API, but we won't dive into that here. What all of this means is:

1. Your `text` variable, which you're trying to parse, is actually an instance of `jqXHR`, not a JSON string.
2. The lines after your call to `$.getJSON` execute before the JSON has even been returned from the server.

Second, if successful, `$.getJSON` does not require you to parse the JSON after fetching it. jQuery handles that internally, so what you receive on success is the already parsed, native JavaScript data structure.

Third, your returned structure does not contain an array in the `data` property, so `obj.data[0].aqi` will never work because you're attempting to access a non-existent index 0 from `data`. `aqi` is a property of the `data` object, so you want `obj.data.aqi`.

Putting all of that together, the following basic example should get you moving:

```
$.getJSON('https://api.waqi.info/feed/london/?token=1f3f4bd260b5067cd3a4397ae81ac18a1e03f246', function (obj) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.data.aqi;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the code you want to run **after** your JSON request has completed into the success function of the `$.getJSON()` method.

You also don't need to parse the JSON either, as that's done for you.

```js
$.getJSON('https://api.waqi.info/feed/london/?token=1f3f4bd260b5067cd3a4397ae81ac18a1e03f246', function(data) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data.data.aqi;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Output</h2>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

The reason this code needs to be moved is that JavaScript will move onto the code outside of `$.getJSON()` while it's still waiting for the response from it's request - meaning you need to *wait* until it's completed. It's worth looking into Asynchronous JavaScript, and the idea of `Promise`'s.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution. You have to handle the answer in the callback method, like for all asynchronous requests.

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.getJSON('https://api.waqi.info/feed/london/?token=1f3f4bd260b5067cd3a4397ae81ac18a1e03f246', function(data) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data.data.aqi;
    });
</script>

<h2>Output</h2>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the callback method to access the response.

```js
$.getJSON('https://api.waqi.info/feed/london/?token=1f3f4bd260b5067cd3a4397ae81ac18a1e03f246', function(data) {
 if( data.status == 'ok' ) {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data.data.aqi;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Output</h2>
<p id="demo"></p>
```